# lxml parser not able to store text in variable

Tags: python, lxml

So I'm new to xml parsing with Python and am having some trouble with the following:

I am searching for specific tags and storing their values into a list which then gets written onto a csv file.

The values with text gets stored fine, but it seems like values with numbers are failing with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Desktop\IDLE - Copy.py", line 19, in <module>
Qty = things.find('PosQuantityAmt', root.nsmap).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

However, when I simply print the exact same line:

```
print(things.find('PosQuantityAmt', root.nsmap).text)
```

I get values out just fine...

```
8400.0000
15666.0000
75.0000
135697.0000
4528.0000
3224.0000
21352.0000
9734.0000
352000.0000
732.0000
2539.0000
37.7370
21007.6700
60.0000
1100.0000
59877.3300
30000.0000
30000.0000
30000.0000
30000.0000
30000.0000
```

here is my code:

```
from lxml import etree
import csv

tree = etree.parse('C:/Desktop/ECDS_POS.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

f = open('C:/Desktop/test.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(f)

head = ['Port Code','ISIN','Qty','Cost']
csvwriter.writerow(head)


for things in root.findall('ROW', root.nsmap):
    lists = []

    portcode = things.find('CustId',root.nsmap).text

    Qty = things.find('PosQuantityAmt', root.nsmap).text

    ISIN = things.find('PosSecIsin', root.nsmap).text

    cost = things.find('PosCostPriceAmt', root.nsmap).text

    lists.append(portcode + ";" + Qty + ";" + ISIN + ";" + cost )
    csvwriter.writerow(lists)

f.close()
```

snippet of the xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<ECDS RowCount="392" ToDate="2017-10-02" FromDate="2017-10-02" Table="POS" ExtractionTime="2017-10-25T17:44:27" 
xmlns="https://cnchedwsvcp01/ecds/pos/1">

-<ROW>

<EntityCod>BZH</EntityCod>

<CustId>707144</CustId>

<PortfId>707144-1</PortfId>

<PosId>SC.707144-1.277639-600.590084....</PosId>

<SystemIdCod>SC</SystemIdCod>

<PosHfmCod>550 05</PosHfmCod>

<PosHfmDsc>Equities</PosHfmDsc>

<PosNameTxt>Hochschild Mining PLC Hochschild Mini/RegSh GBP0.25</PosNameTxt>

<PosValuationDat>2017-10-02</PosValuationDat>

<PosPriceAmt>2.2490</PosPriceAmt>

<PosCcyCod>GBP</PosCcyCod>

<PosPriceTypeCod>0</PosPriceTypeCod>

<PosPriceTypeDsc>UNIT PRICE</PosPriceTypeDsc>

<PosEstimAmt>18891.6000</PosEstimAmt>

<PosEstimRefAmt>25062.4000</PosEstimRefAmt>

<PosEstimRefCcyCod>USD</PosEstimRefCcyCod>

<PosRefRateAmt>0.7537</PosRefRateAmt>

<PosQuantityAmt>8400.0000</PosQuantityAmt>

<PosSecId>277639-600</PosSecId>

<PosSecIsin>GB00B1FW5029</PosSecIsin>

<PosValorenId>2776396</PosValorenId>

<PosSubAssetTypeCod>101</PosSubAssetTypeCod>

<PosSubAssetTypeDsc>EQUITIES</PosSubAssetTypeDsc>

<PosPriceDat>2017-10-24</PosPriceDat>

<XrGroupDsc>EQUITIES</XrGroupDsc>

<XrGroupId>2</XrGroupId>

<PosContractSizeAmt>1</PosContractSizeAmt>

<PosCostEstimAmt>22675.9500</PosCostEstimAmt>

<PosCostEstimRefAmt>30386.3800</PosCostEstimRefAmt>

<PosCostPriceAmt>2.6995</PosCostPriceAmt>

<PosCostPriceRefAmt>3.6176</PosCostPriceRefAmt>

<PosCostPriceRefRateAmt>0.7462</PosCostPriceRefRateAmt>

<PosAssetTypeCod>10</PosAssetTypeCod>

<PosAssetTypeDsc>SHARES</PosAssetTypeDsc>

</ROW>
```

Comment: I get another error: "ValueError: empty namespace prefix is not supported in ElementPath". lxml does not accept `None` in `{None: 'https://cnchedwsvcp01/ecds/pos/1'}`, which is the value of `root.nsmap`.

Comment: I haven't gotten that error. Not sure how to replicate that to investigate, either. If I comment out the Qty and cost variable and adjust  the final lists.append, it runs fine. It seems as if lxml is treating numbers differently than text strings and the .find method bugs out when parsing the tags that contain them...

Comment: Ok, so it ended up being a small problem I hadn't considered: The quantity and cost tags are not present in all of the ROW sections (there are many). So the code was failing because there was nothing to even find. I placed in conditionals to pass if those tags are not present and it populated the csv file just fine.